# Почему требуется QtCore.dll если уже есть QtCore.lib?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, lib

В проекте С++ (который компилируется в динамическую библиотеку) используется библиотека Qt, поэтому в Linker->Input добавлена статическая библиотека `QtCore4.lib`; почему во время использования проектной dll требуется также `QtCore4.dll`?

Comment: А за что минус? Хороший вопрос же.

Comment: @kff: Мы здесь — сборник прикладных знаний. Для выяснения «прекрасно известного факта», о котором идёт речь в вопросе, поисковик приведёт программиста на конкретно эту страницу. И ещё, я бы не применял настолько строгий критерий качества вопроса — иначе на все вопросы можно было бы ответить «прочитайте в документации», что несколько противоречит идее сайта.

Comment: @kff: Это да. Вот здесь и будет теперь главный источник этой информации.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема состоит в том, что файл с расширением `lib` совершенно не обязан содержать ***статическую*** библиотеку. Если кратко, то этот файл содержит внешние по отношению к программе символы и инструкции как с этими символами поступать. Это может быть инструкция о связи с динамически компонуемой библиотекой (DLL) или же инструкция вставки готового откомпилированного кода, содержащегося в lib-файле. *Qt* стандартно распространяется в shared-версии, т.е. откомпилированные программы требуют её DLL, поэтому почти все её lib-файлы - это просто инструкции связи с DLL. Тем самым `QtCore4.lib` просто даёт компоновщику информацию о том, что все перечисленные в ней символы нужно брать из `QtCore4.dll`.

Чтобы избавиться от зависимостей, Qt нужно пересобирать статически.

Answer (score 5):

Потому что эта lib не содержит нужного кода, а является прокладкой между вашим кодом и dll. Ровно та же ситуация с lib для WinAPI.

Comment: А вы не могли бы поподробнее расписать, что именно содержится в «прокладке»?

Comment: @VladD увы, могу опираться только на догадки: IDA как-то очень странно работает с LIB-файлами и никакого кода я там не увидел. Задачи такой у меня как правило не стоит и чем еще ковырять LIB-файлы я не знаю. Вероятно, там инструкции для линкера для заполнения секции импортов и никакого исполняемого кода нет.

Comment: Файлы lib для динамических библиотек содержат таблицу экспортированных имен и адреса точек входа. Больше ничего там нет

Comment: @EvgenyShmidt то-то я думаю нет исполняемого кода...